# Comparando indices de listas no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tendo problemas com listas em python...

```
lateral = []
for i in range(3):
    lateral = float(input("Por favor, informe o valor de cada lado, 
                           seguidamente:" ))
if(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) and (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and
  (lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
    print('Seu triangulo é equilatero')
elif(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) or (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and 
    (lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
    print('Seu triangulo é isoceles')
else:
    print("Se triangulo é escaleno")
```

Mas toda vez que tento, ele informa esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/...../...../MODULO II/E2Q1.py", line 4, in <module>
if(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) and (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and 
(lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Porém a comparação passa normal quando executada de forma direta... 
Poderia me ajudar a entender esse meu erro e como conserta-lo?

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição para tentar entender onde estão o `for` e os `ifs`

Answer (score 2):

Este erro quer dizer que a variável `lateral` não é uma coleção (*array*, *list*, etc.). Ou seja, ela não tem uma implementação do método `__getitem__`.

Você declarou um *array* no início do *script*, mas depois simplesmente reatribuiu esta variável para um `float`.

Suponho que você pretendia adicionar as entradas do usuário ao *array* `lateral`. Pra isso, você precisa adicionar os valores digitados pelo usuário usando o método `append`.

Veja o código corrigido:

```
lateral = []

for i in range(3):
    valor = float(input("Por favor, informe o valor de cada lado, seguidamente:"))
    lateral.append(valor)
    
if((lateral[0] == lateral[1]) and (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and (lateral[0] == lateral[2])):
    print('Seu triangulo é equilatero')
elif(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) or (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and (lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
    print('Seu triangulo é isoceles')
else:
    print("Se triangulo é escaleno")
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso221913)

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no momento em que você recebe os valores pelo `for loop`.
Quando você iniciou a variável você colocou como uma `list`, porém, como Python é uma linguagem que possui tipagem dinâmica, quando você referenciou a variável `lateral` para um `float` ela faz um casting automático e perde as  características de uma `list`.

Algo legal que você pode fazer  para evitar esse tipo de coisa é receber os valores e transforma-los em float "automaticamente"  enquanto monta a lista utilizando algo chamado `list comprehension`. O código ficaria desta forma:

```
lateral = [float(x) for x in input('Informe os valores seguidamente: ').split()]

if((lateral[0] == lateral[1]) and (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and (lateral[0] == lateral[2])):
    print('Seu triangulo é equilatero')
elif(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) or (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and (lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
    print('Seu triangulo é isoceles')
else:
    print("Se triangulo é escaleno")
```

O único requisito para este caso é que os valores de entrada sejam informados na mesma linha.
Se não for o caso é necessário que você faça como foi dito em algumas respostas anteriores e utilize o método `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que lateral começa como sendo uma lista e depois você transforma ele em um float.

Para ler um float e adicionar à lista `lateral`, faça assim:

```
lado = float(input("Por favor, informe o valor de cada 
       lado, seguidamente:" ))
lateral.append(lado)
```

Answer (score 0):

Além das respostas dadas você também pode receber os valores de entrada em uma única linha.

Por exemplo:

```
entradas = input("Por favor, informe o valor de cada lado, seguidamente:" ).split()

lateral = list(map(float,entradas))

if(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) and (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and (lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
    print('Seu triangulo é equilatero')
elif(lateral[0] == lateral[1]) or (lateral[1] == lateral[2]) and (lateral[0] == lateral[2]):
    print('Seu triangulo é isoceles')
else:
    print("Se triangulo é escaleno")
```

Veja funcionando em https://repl.it/JcVB/0